# LuaLatex , how put glyph freely

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex, lua, scripts

Lua are incredible engine. I have a font in ttf and I would put a specific glyph in a specific place.
For example I create a logo.

I need to put  second version of 'a' in (x,y)=(12pt,30pt) from left upper corner.
Next put '失' in 2pt to the right of previous glyph. First glyph are 11.234567pt height second 9.73pt height. Not changing a main font because each glyph will be from different font.

I need:

- set font name
- set height
- width of glyph (meybe with kerning)
- create a page
- put a glyph to the page (I have a number in unicode or other way)

I'm using tex only as engine to create a pdf , everything else I can create himself. Meybe using tikz?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm not know how do it in lua or tikz.  first glyph put in specyfic place, second start in this same place + width prev glyph + small space (for example 0.01pt)

Comment: You can look at [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos?lang=en), which allows one to put boxes at an arbitrary location on the page.